# What is the correct strategy to consume from partitioned EventHub to avoid QuotaExceededException?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am consuming from an Azure EventHub instance through the Java [EventHubClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.eventhubclient?view=azure-java-legacy) implementation. My strategy has been to create and persist a [PartitionReceiver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.partitionreceiver?view=azure-java-legacy) for each partition and call [PartitionReceiver::receiveSync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.partitionreceiver.receivesync?view=azure-java-legacy#com_microsoft_azure_eventhubs_PartitionReceiver_receiveSync_final_int_) periodically.

The EventHub instance has since increased the partition count to 30+ and the same logic is now throwing [QuotaExceededException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.quotaexceededexception?view=azure-java-legacy), looks like we're hitting the maximum receiver limit for our consumer group.

This makes me think my strategy is wrong entirely, what is the standardized way to constantly consume from all partitions of an EventHub instance without surpassing this quota?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maximum number of receivers limit is 5 and it is per partition per consumer group. You should check your code and identify why you are creating 5+ receivers on at least one of the partitions.

Btw, you should implement your consumers with [EventProcessorHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.eventprocessorhost?view=azure-java-legacy) if you don't have a strong reason to be on EventHubClient.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, I'll have to take a look! What are the benefits of EventProcessorHost over EventHubClient?